# Create Complete setup using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, installation

I developed simple Window application using java.

I used Eclipse Juno as my IDE.

I used Hibernate to do database operations.

Now i want to create the complete setup of this project how can i do it?

I know we can create JAR file using Eclipse using Export option.

**But i mean to say i want to create setup in such a way it must include all the things like my database, imported jar files and any other files that are used in my project.**

I think it already gets the imported jar file but it is not including database how to include it?

**In Visual Studio it remains easy to create setup it gives all the options to include database or not and many other.**

**How can we do it using Eclipse?**

Answer (score 0):

You can try exe4j, installer4j kind of tools to create an .exe or a setup.
But I'm not quite sure whether you can pack your database with the application.